# Petición AJAX no funciona

Tags: javascript, ajax, vue.js

Estoy haciendo una pagina para un curso!
Este ejercicio consiste en poner las imagenes que provienen de una API.
Son 6 imagenes distintas,lo he hecho usando Vue.js y jQuery,por lo que tengo entendido esto deberia mostrar las 6 imagenes (sin CSS por lo que se ven todas juntas) pero no lo hace

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="mod" class="container"><div class="row"><div class="col" v-for="dato in datosUsuarios"><img v-bind:src="dato.avatar" alt=""></div></div></div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

y aqui el JS:

```
var app = new Vue({
    el:"#mod",
    data:{

        dataUsers:{}
    }
})
$.ajax({
    url: "API SECRETA",
    success:function(users){
        app.dataUsers=users        },
})
```

No entiendo porque esto no muestra las imagenes en la pagina,en cambio las muestra si especifico cada una de las imagenes por su ruta,ejemplo `{{dataUsers.[0].avatar}}` aunque si hago esto tengo que insertar cada una de las imagenes a mano y ese no seria el punto del ejercicio

Desde ya muchas gracias por leer

Comment: La petición AJAX te devuelve un string, como veo en `data`, intentas definir un objeto, puedes usar [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Comment: Supongo que será por el `v-for`, el cual se renderiza al momento de cargar la página, momento en el cual todavía la petición AJAX no se ha procesado, deberás renderizar las imágenes con `JSON.parse` y [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) en el método `success`

Answer (score 1):

Me equivoqué cuando te dije en los comentarios que usaras `JSON.parse`, pues comprobé que jQuery convierte ya el resultado a JSON

Dándonos cuenta en el resultado de tu petición, la parte que nos interesa es `usuarios.data`, el cual tiene todos los usuarios

Y como te dije en comentarios, el `v-for` se renderiza cuando se carga la página, en ese entonces no se habrá procesado la petición aún, así que Vue iterará un objeto vacío todavia

Así que tendrás que esperar a que la petición se procese y por fin podrás procesar las imágenes

Teniendo en cuenta que `usuarios.data` es un array de objetos, podemos usar o bien [`for of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) o [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) para iterarlo

También le puse una ID a el contenedor de imágenes (`imgcontainer`) para poder referirnos a él con javascript y poder poner las imágenes en el `<div>`

```js
var Vueapp = new Vue({
    el:"#app",
    data:{}
})
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2&data',
    success:function(usuarios){
        for(item of usuarios.data) {
          const div = document.createElement('div');
          const el = document.createElement('img');
          el.setAttribute('src', item.avatar);
          div.appendChild(el);
          div.classList.add('col');
          document.querySelector('#imgcontainer').appendChild(div);
        }
    },
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app" class="container"><div class="row" id="imgcontainer"></div></div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Funciona a la perfección! lo que sucede es que quedan todas las imagenes en el mismo div,y debe quedar cada una en un div separado, o por lo menos que se puedan separar y aplicarles caracteristicas a cada una de las imagenes,es por esto que usaba el v-for para que creara divs para cada uno de los elementos. Muchisimas gracias por el tiempo y la amabilidad

Comment: @fenix0011 He actualizado mi respuesta, ahora el código crea un `<div>` con una imagen dentro de este y se lo añade al contenedor `.row`

Comment: AMIGO,BRO,LO HICE FUNCIONAR CON EL V-FOR,MUCHISIMAS GRACIAS POR TU AYUDA YA QUE DE PENSARLO E INTENTARLO SALIO AL FIN!!!

Answer (score 1):

Esto funciona!!

```js
var app = new Vue({
    el:"#mod",
    data:{

        dataUsers:{}
    }
})
$.ajax({
    url: "API SECRETA",
    success:function(users){
        Vueapp.dataUsers=(users.data)
    },
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="mod" class="container"><div class="row"><div class="col" v-for="data in dataUsers"><img v-bind:src="users.avatar" alt=""></div></div></div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```